# unable to load Assembly

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I'm getting a strange error from my VisualStudio 2008 installation in Windows 7 and I wonder whether anyone knows how to fix that:

> Unable to read the project file
>   "cs.proj". Could not load file or
>   assembly Microsoft.Build.Engine,
>   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   [...] System cannot find the file
>   specified.
>   `

I checked: .Net 3.5 is installed. So does anyone know what that means?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running gacutil -l to check if the MSBuild assemblies are installed

Answer (score 1):

I found a thread on social.msdn.microsoft.com, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/59fa45ee-ac51-4325-83fa-26389a33c22f

Iе offers that the .NET install might be corrupted and suggests uninstall .NET and do a full 3.5 SP1 install.

My IT department did a windows update and it interrupted my VS install with the "MSBuild assembly not found", and I have to wait for them to fix it because I don't have install rights.

Let me know if this works.