# Visual studio conversion error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation, repair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unable to load Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468729/unable-to-load-assembly)

When ever i try to create a new project. I get the following error.

Is there a way to solve this without reinstalling.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Engine,
>   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling .net framework 3.5 from your Visual Studio 2008 disk. In vs2008 express disk it's located at

> I:\VBExpress\WCU\dotNetFramework\dotNetFx35setup.exe

where 'I' represents dvd drive letter.